# bundle install -jailshell: bundle: command not found on shared hosting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, hosting, shared-hosting

Bundle install is not working on shared hosting , but i installed gem bundle , when i ran the following command

i tried

***bundle install***

```
-jailshell: bundle: command not found
```

***so i try to evaluate the following commands***

**gem list bundler -v 1.1.4**

```
*** REMOTE GEMS ***

bundler (1.1.4)
bundler-auto-update (0.0.4)
bundler-bootstrap (0.0.3)
bundler-bouncer (0.1.2)
bundler-fastupdate (0.0.3)
bundler-github (0.2.0)
bundler-maglev- (1.0.21)
bundler-talks (0.0.4)
bundler08 (0.8.5)
bundler_bash_completion (0.1.1)
bundler_geminabox (0.0.1)
bundler_local_development (0.3.0)
bundler_push_host (0.0.1)
bundler_timer (1.1.2)
```

bundler has installed , but i don't know why its not working?

when i ran

**gem env**

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.15
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/username/ruby/gems
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/username/ruby/gems/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/username/ruby/gems
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gempath" => []
     - "gem" => "--remote --gen-rdoc --run-tests"
     - "gemhome" => "/home/username/ruby/gems"
     - "rdoc" => "--inline-source --line-numbers"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

**echo $PATH**

```
/usr/local/jdk/bin:/home/username/perl5/bin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/lib/courier-imap/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/home/username/bin
```

**uname -mrsn**

```
Linux osprey.arvixe.com 2.6.18-374.3.1.el5.lve0.8.44 x86_64
```

**more /proc/version**

```
Linux version 2.6.18-374.3.1.el5.lve0.8.44 (mockbuild@buildfarm.cloudlinux.com)
(gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-51)) #1 SMP Mon Oct 3 18:27:54 EEST 2
011
```

**which gem**

```
/usr/bin/gem
```

**which ruby**

```
/usr/bin/ruby
```

**which rails**

```
/usr/bin/rails
```

**ruby -v**

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [x86_64-linux]
```

**rails -v**

```
Rails 2.3.14
```

**gem -v**

```
1.8.15
```

**locate bundle**

```
locate: can not open `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db': Permission denied
```

***Guys Please help me basic bundle install command is not working , so i don't know what todo and also i am new to ruby on rails.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem, hosting guys need to give some permissions.

you always need to install gems on our home directory particularly in shared hosting

```
bundle install --path /home/username/bundle
```